# Terraform - AWS AppSync Graph API with Lambda Authoriser

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-appsync

I'm trying to use a Lambda authoriser with the [AppSync module](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appsync_graphql_api) for Terraform.

Here's my current terraform

```
module "appsync" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/appsync/aws"

  name = "api-appsync-${var.region}-${var.stage_name}"

  schema = file("modules/appsync/schema.graphql")

  api_keys = {
    default = null # such key will expire in 7 days
  }

  additional_authentication_provider = {
    iam = {
      authentication_type = "AWS_IAM"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I have the lambda authoriser working but currently have to update the AppSync settings manually after each deployment.

Answer (score 0):

It should be available on *terraform-provider-aws* v3.70.0.

[Here's the PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/20857).

Waiting for that, you can use:

```sh
aws appsync update-graphql-api \
            --no-cli-auto-prompt \
            --name "$PROJECT_NAME" \
            --api-id "$APPSYNC_ID" \
            --authentication-type "AWS_LAMBDA" \
            --lambda-authorizer-config "{ \"authorizerResultTtlInSeconds\": 300, \"authorizerUri\": \"$LAMBDA_AUTH_APPSYNC_ARN\" }"
```

Comment: I see this PR is merged now. Awesome! Thank you @Pharb !
A new release version has not yet been tagged though. I am still getting the Error: Unsupported argument when using the lambda_authorizer_config argument with version 3.69. How can I get the latest version of code which will include this PR. Here is my versions.tf file

```terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.69"
    }
  }
}```